# How to configure desktop and toolbar menu to be the same to all users

Tags: desktop-environments, menu-bar

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS.

I want to know if I can to set the desktop and toolbar menu to be exactly the same to all the users of the computer.

I'm talking about when I start the system with my administrator account, I can see some app icons into the desktop, in some order, with some specific background, and with some specific toolbar menu, but... When I use another account (Invited), there is nothing from my administrator account into the screen monitor (I just can see the first post-installation screen, without any personal setting).

Can I change this? How?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux the `/etc/skel` directory contains all the files that a new user will get copied into their home directory when first created. You can copy all of your settings into that directory using:

```
sudo cp -r /home/someuser/.confg /etc/skel
sudo cp -r /home/someuser/.local /etc/skel
sudo cp -r /home/someuser/.gconf /etc/skel
```

This worked in my testing in a VM. Copying other directories might help you "sync" settings between other apps and programs but I did run into some errors where trying to do that with certain files (like `.gnupg`) caused `adduser` to fail when adding new users.

Comment: Your idea didn't work to me. I followed all your steps and... Nothing! With the "Visit" account I just have the first post-installation screen, nothing from the Administrator account screen.